# Jna external library and jvm exception instead of crash

Tags: java, native, jna

I had to link my java app to an external library using JNA.
I don't have its source and then I can't change it.
Sometimes happeneds that this external library crash the jvm of my app, I don't know what can be... Maybe an unmanaged exception of the external library, what I see is just a app crash when an external native method is called.
Is there any way to avoid the entire jvm crash and simply get an Exception by JNA?

To better detail the problem: this library is a smartcard driver. During some s.o. auto-update or after the s.o. standby process sometimes I got that crash. No logs or errors, just the end of the jvm process.

Answer (score 2):

JNA provides a system property, `jna.protected`, which if set true will result in an exception rather than a crash.  This is enabled by default on windows, but on other platforms you need to pre-link with `libjsig.so`, since JNA uses some of the same signals used by the JVM to catch memory faults.

From [the JavaDoc](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/overview-summary.html#crash-protection):

> It is not uncommon when defining a new library and writing tests to
>   encounter memory access errors which crash the VM. These are often
>   caused by improper mappings or invalid arguments passed to the native
>   library. To generate Java errors instead of crashing the VM, call
>   `Native.setProtected(true)`. Not all platforms support this protection;
>   if not, the value of `Native.isProtected()` will remain false.
>
> **NOTE**:
>
> When protected mode is enabled, you should make use of the `jsig`
>   library, if available (see *Signal Chaining*) to avoid interfering with
>   the JVM's use of signals. In short, set the environment variable
>   `LD_PRELOAD` (or `LD_PRELOAD_64`) to the path to `libjsig.so` in your JRE
>   lib directory (usually `${java.home}/lib/${os.arch}/libjsig.so`) before
>   launching your Java application.

Even so, it's not recommended for production code, and certainly not recommended to attempt to continue execution after the fault occurs.

Comment: This would be interesting... but I'm working in a Windows enviroment, so the protected mode should be already active?

Comment: You can check via `Native.isProtected()`. JNA won't help you if the exception happens outside of a call via JNA.  If the native code chokes on some other native thread you're out of luck.

Comment: If you can get the crash dump file it should have the Java stack where the crash occurred.

Comment: `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib` contains `libjsig.dylib` on OSX, so you should be able to enable by setting [`DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`](https://blogs.oracle.com/DatabaseEmporium/entry/where_is_ld_preload_under)